# how to bind the relevant value in case of current status in ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have attached data attribute in each `.state` to identify the user (authenticated or public) as following (one state example)

```
$stateProvider
 .state('admin-panel.public.home', {
    url: '/p',
    templateUrl: 'app/public/home.tmpl.html',
    controller: 'PublicHomeController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    data: {
        requireLogin: false
    }
});
```

I need to use the some state for both of user (authenticated and public) as an example

```
.state('403', {
    url: '/403',
    templateUrl: '403.tmpl.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state, APP, Auth) {
        $scope.app = APP;

        $scope.goHome = function() {
            if(Auth.isAuthenticated()){
                $scope.requireLogin = true;
                $state.go('admin-panel.default.home');
            }
            else{
                $scope.requireLogin = false;
                $state.go('admin-panel.public.home');
            }
        };
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: $scope.requireLogin
    }                

})
```

Here when the authenticated user access this state I need to pass the true value to `requireLogin: true` as well when public user access this state I need to pass the `false` value as `requireLogin: false`. I checked the current user status in the `controller` as above. How can I bind the `$scope.requireLogin` to data attribute?

Anyone in expert of `ui-router` please tell a way to solve???

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem in a very cleaner way. Let's start with a global controller example `GlobalCtrl` which is added to the `body` or `html` tag like `ng-controller="GlobalCtrl`.

Doing this will enable us to keep the scope of this `GlobalCtrl` throughout your single page Angular app (as you are using `ui-router`) and we can avoid the usage of `$rootScope` (actually mimicking the usage of `$rootScope`).

Now, inside your `GlobalCtrl` define something like this:

```
// Using an object to avoid the scope inheritance problem of Angular
// https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
$scope.globalData = {};

// Will be called everytime before you start navigating to any state
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
    $scope.globalData.requireLogin = false;
    var statesToLoginCheck = ['403', 'foo', 'bar']; // and other states on which you want to check if user is logged in or not

    // If the current state on which we are navingating is allowed to check for login
    if (statesToLoginCheck.indexOf(toState.name) > -1) {
        if (Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            $scope.globalData.requireLogin = true;
            $state.go('admin-panel.default.home');
        } else {
            $scope.globalData.requireLogin = false;
            $state.go('admin-panel.public.home');
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

Now, since `$scope` of `GlobalCtrl` is in `body` or `html` then every state or directive will inherit the scope of this `GlobalCtrl` and then you simply have to check in your any controller of variable `$scope.globalData.requireLogin`.

Comment: You are telling we don't need this(data: {
        requireLogin: $scope.requireLogin
    }         ) in each state right?