# how to attach variable to custom data to state object in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I want to attach the the variable which came from controller to data object

```
.state('403', {
    url: '/403',
    templateUrl: '403.tmpl.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state, APP, Auth) {
        $scope.app = APP;

        $scope.goHome = function() {
            if(Auth.isAuthenticated()){
                $scope.state = true;
                $state.go('admin-panel.default.home');
            }
            else{
                $scope.state = false;
                $state.go('admin-panel.public.home');
            }
        };
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: $scope.state;
    }                        
})
```

I want to attach **$scope.state** value to *requireLogin of data object*.

How can i do it? please help to do it???

Comment: it is weird, why do you want to do that? I'm sure you can do what you need to do better.

Comment: Amir please see this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237801/how-to-bind-the-relevant-value-in-case-of-current-status-in-ui-router/34237891#34237891)
this whtat i want to do

Comment: That question already have a nice answer, why dont you go with that?